# Counting the number of time series in a time range

Tags: kubernetes, time-series, devops, prometheus

I'm trying to get deployment frequency in Kubernetes. Counting replicasets doesn't work for us since we want to see the frequency of 'code deploys'. We can look at how many different images were deployed for a workload in a time window. I'm trying to get this data from Prometheus which has Kubernetes metrics along with kube-state-metrics.

I have tried things like:

```
count(
  group by (image) (
    (label_replace(kube_pod_owner{owner_kind="ReplicaSet", owner_name=~"app-.*"}, "replicaset", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)")
      * on (replicaset) group_left kube_replicaset_spec_replicas{} 
    > 0)
    * on (pod) group_right kube_pod_container_info{container="app"}
  )
)
```

```
count(
  group by (image) (
    (count_over_time(kube_pod_container_info{container="app", pod=~"app.*"}[1d])
      * on(pod) group_left kube_pod_container_status_ready{}
    ) > 1
  )
)
```

Which aren't giving me quite what I want. I get a spike in the graph for the period where two images exist simultaneously, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: hard to understand the problem in detail. It would be nice if you break the query down. I suspect that your problem is on the `group by`. have you tried other aggregate operators (e.g.: `sum`, `max`, `count`). Maybe it is because you are using 2 aggregate operators nested, `count` then `group`? why are you doing that? Why not use only one `count by(image) ....`?

Comment: I did try other aggregators, but I want to be able to say how many changes happened in a time window and couldn't quite manage to articulate that. (will edit to add detail later)

Comment: There is a function that calculate `changes()` ([docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes)), is that what you were looking for?

Comment: changes counts changes to the same time series